# The form in which the Boolean Field field must always be true. Django

Tags: django, forms

I am trying to add a restriction so that the user always selects the checkbox to 'True'. It looks like that, but unfortunately it does not work properly. Any help will be appreciated.

**models.py**

```
class OrderingMassage(models.Model):
    website_rules = models.BooleanField(default=None, blank=True)
```

**forms.py**

```
class OrderingMassageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = OrderingMassage
        fields = ('website_rules')

    def clean_website_rules(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data['website_rules']
        if data == None:
            raise forms.ValidationError("please accept the rules of the website")
        else:
            return data
```

Comment: You do not need a `Model` for that. If it is always `True`, it is strange to save that in the database, you just need a form that is valid for that.

Comment: What does "does not work properly" mean?

Comment: I can check the box or do not check and the form does not return an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If something always (should be) true, then you should not use a `Model` in the first place. A model stores data. But if all records all have the same, then there is not much data. If a column is always `True`, then what is the use to store that column?

A second problem you have is that a [**`BooleanField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/fields/#booleanfield) (well the form field) will yield `False` as "empty value. So it is probably more Pythonic to check the truthiness, like:

```
class OrderingMassageForm(forms.Form):
    website_rules = forms.BooleanField(label='I accept the rules of the website.')

    def clean_website_rules(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data['website_rules']
        if not data:
            raise forms.ValidationError("please accept the rules of the website")
        else:
            return data
```

You thus do *not* need to call `.save()` of that form. But `.is_valid(..)` will validate the form, and thus can render errors.

Comment: It works! and does not allow you to forward the form. But an error message is not displayed. Do I need to add a special tag to my field type in my html code? the remaining fields are displayed correctly.  or maybe because it added widgets?

Comment: @MaddieGraham: how exactly do you *render* the form? Can you edit your question with the form part in your template?